# What is the relationship of binding and dispatching ? Are they the same?

Tags: java, oop

I have seen some resources where it state that dynamic dispatch and the late binding are the same. If so then `binding` should be equal to `dispatching`. In some places they state `overloading/early binding/ static dispatch` as same and `overriding/late binding/ dynamic dispatch` as same.

So I came up with an analogy to understand this. ***Is the below analogy correct ?*** or how can I modify the below explanations.

We have a class structure as below.

```
class Board {
    public void show(){};
}

class Shape{
    public void draw(Board board) {};
}

class Square extends Shape {
    public void draw(Board board) {
        System.out.println("Drawing a Square");
    };
}

class Circle extends Shape {
    public void draw(Board board) {
        System.out.println("Drawing a Circle");
    };
}
```

We have :

```
Shape shape = createShape(type); // This will return any of Shape, Square, Circle
shape.draw(board);
```

We have :

```
Board myBoard = new Board();
myBoard.show();
```

And I came up with few explanations,

> **Binding** : Deciding the actual type for the `shape` (can be Shape, Square or Circle). Given that if type of `shape` is known only at the run time it is `late binding`. Deciding type of `myBoard`  can be done in compile time. Which is `early binding`
>
> **Dispatching** :  Deciding the actual implementation for `draw` is considered `dispatching`. Given that if the actual implementation of `draw` can only be decided at run time it is `dynamic dispatching` otherwise if it can be decided at compile time it is called `static dispatching`
>
> **Static Dispatch** : Happens when I know at compile time which function body will be executed when I call a method. So `myBoard.show()`, here the method `show` can be statically dispatched. Where `shape.draw(board)` we can't dispatch `draw` statically since we can't guarantee which function body will be executed at runtime.
>
> **Single Dispatch (Dynamic)** : An implementation for the `draw` will be chosen based only on `shape`'s type, disregarding the type or value of `board`.
>
> **Multiple Dispatch (Dynamic)** : The types of the `shape` and `board` together determine which `draw` operation will be performed. (In this case it is `Double Dispatch`)

Few resources I used :

- https://lukasatkinson.de/2016/dynamic-vs-static-dispatch/
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200115/what-is-early-and-late-binding/200123#200123
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch
- http://net-informations.com/faq/oops/binding.htm
- [What is the difference between Binding and Dispatching in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524479/what-is-the-difference-between-binding-and-dispatching-in-java)

Comment: "If so then `binding` should be equal to `dispatching`." - I wouldn't say that. "Binding" refers to associating an identifier to a method. "Dispatching" refers to making the actual call. But if you "bind late", there's no point in dispatching to a statically decided method. If you "bind early" you don't have a choice, you must select a method at compile time.

Comment: So is late binding is actually dynamic dispatching ? What can you say about the above explanations, are the explanations correct then ?

Comment: Sure, late binding can be seen as synonym to dynamic dispatch. (You can't really have one without the other.) Re. **Binding**: Not the actual type for `shape`, what _method_ to call which Java happens to do based on the type of `shape`. **Dispatching**: LGTM. **Static Dispatch**: Well, `Board.show` could be overridden. I'd agree if the method was static or if `Board` and/or `Board.show` was final. **Single Dispatch/Multiple Dispatch**: Well, could be argument type, could technically be some other attribute too, like type of `shape` + phase of the moon.

Comment: So basically it to be static dispatch the method should be non-virtual ?

Comment: @aioobe so the single and multiple explanations are correct but there can be other scenarios and combinations as well, this is what you meant I guess.

Comment: Well, if the result of the method is statically decidable you can dispatch it statically. (I assume you've read the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_dispatch).)

Answer (score 1):

To finally give this question an answer:

*Binding* and *dispatch* are not the same.

- *Binding* in general refers to resolving a symbol to some value/object/implementation. For example, an assignment statement `x = 42` binds the symbol `x` to the value of the expression `42`. Type names can always be resolved during compile time in Java.
- *Dispatch* (or more precisely *call dispatch* or *method dispatch*) is the kind of binding that resolves a method call (or function call) to a method implementation. With *static dispatch* or *early binding* the target of that call can be known at compile time, with *dynamic dispatch* or *late binding* of method calls the target is selected at run time.

  Interface methods or virtual methods (the default in Java) use dynamic dispatch. Final methods, private methods, and static methods are effectively statically dispatched (though strictly speaking, the JVM still has to resolve the call).

I'll also quickly mention that the *static type* of an expression is the statically known or “declared” type of an expression, and that the *dynamic type* is the actual type of the runtime value of that expression. E.g. when we declare a variable `Board b`, then the static type of `b` is the `Board` class but the dynamic type might be `Board` or any of its subclasses – we don't know until it is assigned a particular object. A dynamically dispatched method can be bound as soon as the dynamic type is known (assuming type-based single dispatch as in Java).

Your `myBoard.show()` example uses a virtual method and would usually be dynamically dispatched: `myBoard` is declared to have type `Board` or any `Board`-subclass. This would change if you declare the class or `show()` as final. In practice, this particular example can be optimized to static dispatch because you construct the `new Board()` in the same scope, so the dynamic type of `myBoard` is known. But that is only an optimization.

In contrast, your `createShape().draw()` example clearly is dynamic dispatch, because the dynamic type of `createShape()` is not known by the caller.

Your understanding of single dispatch/multiple dispatch is essentially correct.

I'd like to point out that “dispatching” in its general sense of resolving a function call is not necessarily restricted to *types*. We could also dispatch a call using logic in if/elses. Consider this example where we dispatch a `quadrant(x,y)` call to a specific quadrant like north-east, depending on the values of x and y. This is static dispatch from the perspective of the language, but behaves more like static dispatch from the perspective of a programmer.

```
class Quadrants {
  ...
  public static void quadrant(int x, int y, String value) {
    // dispatch a call with a x→east, y→north coordinate system
    if (x >= 0) {
      if (y >= 0) {
        quadrantNE(value);
      } else {
        quadrantSE(value);
      }
    } else {
      if (y >= 0) {
        quadrantNW(value);
      } else {
        quadrantSW(value);
      }
    }
  }
  private static void quadrantNE(String value) { ... }
  private static void quadrantNW(String value) { ... }
  private static void quadrantSE(String value) { ... }
  private static void quadrantSW(String value) { ... }
}
```

Under the hood, a language runtime would also just use some logic to perform dynamic dispatch, especially for multi-dispatch. Type-based single dispatch (like instance method calls in Java where the static type is a class) can be implemented with a simple table lookup (vtable dispatch) and doesn't need complicated logic.